# Using multiple buttons calling same parameterized controller function in Play application

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am making an application where I display a list of all online users with a separate button next to each user.
Clicking the button should call the controller function with user id corresponding to this entry.

For the same I have:

```
<div class="span4 box-widget">
    <div>
    <h5 align="center">Buddy List</h5>
      <ul class="unstyled">
         @if(xmppuser !=null){
            @for(p <-xmppuser.getOnlinefrnds())
            {
             <li>
             <span>@p.getPresence()</span>
             <span>@p.getName()</span>
             <button class="btn btn-warning" 
             onclick="@Presencelanding.sendChallenge(p.getName())">Challenge</button>
             </li>
             }
           }
      </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

However whenever I refresh the webpage this function gets called.
Also no function call is invoked/triggered by clicking this button

How do I implement the same?

Comment: `@routes.Presencelanding.sendChallenge(p.getName())` gives you the URI, `@Presencelanding.sendChallenge(p.getName())` executes the method. Don't know what you are planning to do, though. Putting a URI into an `onclick` attribute won't do any good.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This helps. But in that case how do i invoke method on button click event? Do i have to have a form individually for each buddy element ?

Comment: AJAX! Create a small Javascript function that takes an URL as parameter and makes a request. No need for forms at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="location.href='sssss'"
routes:
GET/sssss                           controller.****.yourfunction()
```